# c socket send file size and then the file

Tags: c, sockets, sendfile

This is a snippet of *client.c*:

```
size_t fsize;
int total_bytes_read = 0, ret_val;

hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
DescrittoreClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(DescrittoreClient, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
strcpy(Buffer, filename);
send(DescrittoreClient, Buffer, strlen(Buffer), 0);
ret_val = read(DescrittoreClient, &fsize, sizeof(fsize));
if(ret_val == -1){
    printf("Errore durante ricezione grandezza file\n");
    close(DescrittoreClient);
    exit(1);
}

fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0644);
if (fd  < 0) {
    perror("open");
    exit(1);
}

while(total_bytes_read < fsize){
    while ((nread = read(DescrittoreClient, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer))) > 0){
        write(fd, Buffer, nread);
        total_bytes_read += nread;
    }
}
printf("File ricevuto\n");
```

And this is a snippet of *server.c*:

```
int DescrittoreServer, DescrittoreClient, LunghezzaClient;
int NumPorta = atoi(argv[1]);
char Buffer[1024] = {};
int rc, fd;
off_t offset = 0;
struct stat stat_buf;
char filename[1024] = {};
int fsize[10240] = {};

DescrittoreServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(bind(DescrittoreServer, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    perror("Errore di bind\n");
    close(DescrittoreServer);
    exit(1);
}
listen(DescrittoreServer, 5);
LunghezzaClient = sizeof(cli_addr);
while(1){
    DescrittoreClient = accept(DescrittoreServer, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &LunghezzaClient);

rc = recv(DescrittoreClient, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);

fprintf(stderr, "Ricevuta richiesta di inviare il file: '%s'\n", filename);

/* open the file to be sent */
fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

/* get the size of the file to be sent */
fstat(fd, &stat_buf);
*fsize = stat_buf.st_size;
send(DescrittoreClient, fsize, sizeof(fsize), 0);

/* copy file using sendfile */
offset = 0;
rc = sendfile(DescrittoreClient, fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
if (rc != stat_buf.st_size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Trasferimento incompleto: %d di %d bytes\n", rc, (int)stat_buf.st_size);
    exit(1);
}   

    close(DescrittoreClient);
    close(fd);
}
```

What does this code do:
1) client sends the name of a file
2) server sends the length (in byte) of the file
3) client receives the length of the file
4) server sends the file
5) client receives the file
The problem is that the file **is not** entirely received but only a part of it is written by the client (for example a file of 2143 byte is sent by the server and only 95 byte are received by the client) and i don't understand why!
PS: some errors handling have been deleted so the code is more readable!

Comment: @nos i don't undestand! i've declared fsize[10240] on the client!

Comment: He's saying that `sizeof(fsize)` is 10240. That's how many bytes you are sending with your second `send()` on the client.

Comment: @polslinux But `recv(DescrittoreClient, fsize, sizeof(fsize), 0);` might not read all those bytes, it might read less than `sizeof(fsize)` (Remember, TCP gives you a stream of bytes, it does not preserve any message/packet boundaries)

Comment: @nos and how can i fix this??

Comment: @polslinux: you might like to read here: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: i've updated the client's code but still not working :(

Comment: (fsize != ret_val) You should loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call recv() in a loop and sum up it's return values:

```
while (read_bytes < filesize) {
    read_bytes += recv(socket, buffer + read_bytes, filesize-read_bytes, flags)
}
```

of course you should also add error handling, i.e., check if you read 0 bytes and the connection was closed.

Comment: thanks for your answer but with your code i got "error: too many arguments to function ‘read’"

Comment: sorry, i meant to use recv instead of read. read() does not take a flags argument. Otherwise it's the same techique.

Comment: yea i've seen after my comment xD

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i have declared `char nread=0` instead of `int nread=0` into the client and so the maximum value i can read with `char` is 127...changed char to int solved my problem!

Comment: size_t would have been an even better choice :) That's what read actually expects.